# Constructing variable lags based on additional condition

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, transform, tidyr

I want to create a lagged variable based on the following additional condition and operations:

- When the lag (previous row) of the variable (day_active) is 1, it should also take the lag of the variable n_wins
- When the lag (previous row) of day_active is 0, it should just repeat the value of n_wins of the previous row as long as day_active remains 0.

Let's assume we observe a game player for ten days. day_active indicates if he was active on that day and n_wins indicates the number of games he won.

```
Example dataset:
    da = data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), day_active = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1), n_wins = c(2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))

da
   day day_active n_wins
1    1          1      2
2    2          1      3
3    3          0      0
4    4          0      0
5    5          1      1
6    6          1      0
7    7          0      0
8    8          0      0
9    9          1      0
10  10          1      1
```

This is how it should look after the transformation:

```
da2 = data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), day_active = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1), n_wins = c(2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), lag_n_wins = c(NA,2,3,3,3,1,0,0,0,0))
da2
   day day_active n_wins lag_n_wins
1    1          1      2         NA
2    2          1      3          2
3    3          0      0          3
4    4          0      0          3
5    5          1      1          3
6    6          1      0          1
7    7          0      0          0
8    8          0      0          0
9    9          1      0          0
10  10          1      1          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a grouping column based on the presence of 1 in 'day_active' by taking the cumulative sum of logical vector, then `if` all the values are not 0, replace with `NA` and replace the `NA` with the previous non-NA element with `na.locf` (from `zoo`), `ungroup` and take the `lag` of the column created

```
library(dplyr)    
da %>%
     group_by(grp = cumsum(day_active == 1)) %>%
     mutate(lag_n_wins = zoo::na.locf0(if(all(n_wins == 0)) n_wins 
                  else na_if(n_wins, 0)) ) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     mutate(lag_n_wins = lag(lag_n_wins)) %>%
     select(-grp)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#     day day_active n_wins lag_n_wins
#   <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1     1          1      2         NA
# 2     2          1      3          2
# 3     3          0      0          3
# 4     4          0      0          3
# 5     5          1      1          3
# 6     6          1      0          1
# 7     7          0      0          0
# 8     8          0      0          0
# 9     9          1      0          0
#10    10          1      1          0
```